# Looping dataframes from api in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I need to repeat the same manipulation process from multiple dataframe  using quandl api.

How can I start a loop in this case ?

For example, if I use those 2 data:

```
dfd = quandl.get("FRED/DEXBZUS")
dfe = quandl.get("ECB/EURBRL")
df=[dfd,dfe]

for i in df:
    df1=[i]
    df1= df1.reset_index()
```

But I got this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reset_index'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error arises because you trying to manipulate with the list and not DataFrame. When you starting to loop through the **df** list you already have the DataFrame in your **i** variable. So the solution should be:

```
for i in df:
    i.reset_index(inplace=True)
```